# Jquery and input text onchange show pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have spent far too much trying to get a simple jquery and input box example to work.

When someone finishes typing something into the input box, I want jquery to popup an alert. Eventually I will be doing some more code with this but right now I just want to get this working!

Here is my example, which doesn't seem to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#selector').change(function () {
    alert($('#selector').val());
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="selector">
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered hundreds of times all over the place. Either move your javascript to AFTER the element is created or (preferably) put your code in `$(document).ready(function() { //code here });` You're referring to an element that doesn't yet exist.

Comment: Change will trigger on focus change. It works best on dropdowns. Use keyup instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your jquery inside `document.ready()` as shown :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#selector').change(function () {
    alert($('#selector').val());
  });
});
</script>
```

[Read More here about `document.ready()`.](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

**EDIT :-** If you want to alert on **'someone finishes typing(as given in your question)'** then use `.focusout()` event as shown :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selector').focusout(function () {
     alert($('#selector').val());
    });
  });
  </script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/coyhnodx/)

Answer (score 3):

Add Document ready.

```
$(function(){

   $('#selector').change(function () {

     alert($('#selector').val());

   });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use .focusout

```
$('#selector').focusout(function () {
alert($('#selector').val());
});
```

working example http://jsfiddle.net/2w7gyjgy/

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your code in a document ready handler -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#selector').change(function () {
          alert($('#selector').val());
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)** in your script yo bootstrap on page

```
$(document).ready(function(){// apply this
 $('#selector').change(function () {
    alert($('#selector').val());
 });
});
```